# Android 5.0.0 on Nexus 5 stuck on boot logo

Tags: boot, nexus-5, stock-android, 5.0-lollipop

I just recently received the 5.0 update for my Nexus 5 and now my device fails to boot. All that happens is the Google logo gets displayed on the screen and then the device does nothing else. I am able to get into both the bootloader and recovery.

First I tried wiping the cache with no results. Next I did a full factory reset with no results. After that I decided to just flash the factory images directly. Unfortunately this didn't work either. I went back into recovery and discovered that there were a series of error messages displayed in the recovery menu...

```
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/misc
E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
```

Also after these messages were displayed I could not wipe the cache or do another factory reset.

Luckily I am able to flash the 4.4.4 factory images and boot the device successfully so my guess is that something might be going wrong with the installation.

Has anyone else encountered similar errors when updating to 5.0?

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet that has worked for me, besides reverting to KitKat. This issue also happens for me when I try to do the 5.0.1 update as well. I haven't tried the 5.0.2 update yet but I probably will soon.

Comment: OK thanks. I gave up messing around and bought a new Nexus 5! Kind of wasteful, but nothing worked and I really needed to fix a bug asap.

Comment: By the way, when reverting to Android 4.x, do you find the camera and other apps crash instantly on boot and become unusable?

Comment: I have been considering just buying a new one too but I've just been making due with KitKat for now. When I revert to 4.4.4 my device is stable and I do not have any app crashes. My only issue it my bootloader no longer wants to relock itself. Every time I reboot it unlocks.