# Stock Nexus 5 stuck on Google word on boot

Tags: nexus-5

My nexus suddenly froze. I was on whatsapp when it happened. A few apps were being (auto) updated in the background and AVG was scanning each app as it finished downloading and updating. I usually don't pay attention to it.. and always, every time AVG scans the app, my keyboard goes down. It's a bit annoying, but nothing major.

Today, after the last app was scanned, (at least I think it was the last one) - instead of my keyboard disappearing, my phone just froze. It wouldn't respond to anything on touch screen and not even to volume/power buttons.

Googling a bit told me to hold both volume buttons, with the power button to do a force restart, as I was out of the option of just taking the battery out.

Now, the phone is stuck on the first start screen - the screen that says 'GOOGLE' and nothing. Usual fix to this seems to be factory reset - I did that. I've got everything I need backed up so don't care about losing data - but that just brings me back to the google screen.

The second screen on recovery mode - the one you get by going to recovery mode and holding power button + press release volume up... I see some errors at the bottom saying

```
E: failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
```

and a bunch of similar errors.

This is a stock android with latest lollipop (or the latest that's been released to nexus 5) and I have not messed with the phone in any way... So I am understandably a bit disappointed it's got a problem, esp as the phone is less than a year old.

So, Is there a way to fix this please?

---

Edit: After chatting with google support team and walking through some troubleshooting steps, turned out to be a hardware problem with ROM and I was suggested to contact the seller.. I spoke to amazon and am having to return the phone for a full refund.

Comment: Does fastboot still work?

Comment: Did you attempt to wipe the cache partition?

Comment: @ThomasMartin hi - yes, I did attempt to wipe the cache partition, nothing happens.. as in, it restarts and gets stuck on google word screen again

Comment: @aureljared yes, fastboot works (if fastboot means going to the recovery screen thing...)

Comment: Looks very similar to this issue- http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88501/android-5-0-0-on-nexus-5-stuck-on-boot-logo
Have you had any drops or water spills? Since the phone is less than a year old, I would go ahead and call google support (or whoever you purchased the phone from) and see what they have to say.

Comment: @ThomasMartin Had no water spills at all, no damage whatsoever, haven't  even dropped it. I bought it off of amazon, and it says the item is not eligible for returns.. it does look awfully similar to that problem!

Comment: @iamserious they should still support the phone, depending on how the warranty works through a third party. I would try contacting them through the options at the upper left of this page- https://support.google.com/nexus#topic=3415518 I had an issue a while back with my N7 and they were pretty good about it.

Comment: @ThomasMartin thank you, maybe you can put your comment as the answer and I'll accept it? It turned out to be a hardware fault and I will have to send back the phone for a refund.

Comment: @iamserious anytime. And thanks for the answer credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware problem. Google will support the device even if it was not purchased directly from them, since it's still under warranty. Try contacting them through the options at the upper left of their support page- [support.google.com/nexus](https://support.google.com/nexus)